# Why does Junos create two entries in LIB for single tag- one with "S=0" and other with implicit "S=1"?

Tags: juniper, mpls

In the penultimate LSR there are following two entries for label `301040`:

```
root@r2> show route table mpls.0 protocol rsvp

mpls.0: 14 destinations, 14 routes (14 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

301040             *[RSVP/7/1] 00:06:53, metric 1
                    > to 172.22.201.14 via ge-0/0/2.0, label-switched-path r1->r4
301040(S=0)        *[RSVP/7/1] 00:06:53, metric 1
                    > to 172.22.201.14 via ge-0/0/2.0, label-switched-path r1->r4

root@r2>
```

Am I correct, that one should look the `S=0` as a condition, i.e if the `S=0`(bottom of stack bit in MPLS header is not set) then do **something** and this **something** can be different when the `S=1`(bottom of stack bit in MPLS header is set)? For example, LSR could swap the label `301040` with label `12345` if it is at the bottom of the stack or pop the label `301040` if it is not at the bottom of the stack.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

S=0 means that the label is not at the bottom at the stack.
In some situations, a packet may contain more than 1 label, and each of these labels serves a different purpose. In this case, we can force the router to process such a packet differently than a packet with only one label.
Please refer to this(label stacking section):
https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/command-summary/show-route-table.html